# xpath to get a simple div id="xyz" with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

the html I'm digging (there is no iframe on it) is:

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
```

I try to get the block of the DOM tree corresponding to the above `div`

this is my code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    app = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="app"]')
    print(4444444444444444, app)
    is_vue_app_loaded = len(app.text) != 0
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(f'e: {e}')
```

I get this error:

```
 4444444444444444 <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
 (session="c8da2a89-63fd-4dce-bdb5-28fdf0e67b01",
  element="b9be2828-115e-4965-8ebc-b75c09236193")>

 e: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@id='app']
```

Is there a way to ask the driver to return me the raw html so I can check that the DOM try I think I have is the one I have actualy ?

Comment: Check the element is present inside any iframe??

Comment: Looking at the output the element was found `4444444444444444 <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement`. Are you sure the error is from this code?

Comment: @user3313834 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I've edited the question to precise what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Check if the element is present inside any `iframe`.If there you need to switch it first.

If Not then try.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app' and @class='container-fluid']")))
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is to return me the raw html of the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` inconjunction with `get_attribute("outerHTML")` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container-fluid#app"))).get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='container-fluid' and @id='app']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```